# Azure PowerShell cmdlet Set-AzRouteConfig

Tags: azure, azure-powershell

I am trying to find out how Azure PowerShell cmdlet Set-AzRouteConfig works under the hood , what calls it makes to Azure APIs etc. The goal is to achieve a similar functionality using Azure SDK for Python.

Comment: If the answer was helpful, Please [Accept it as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work), so that others who encounter the same issue can find this solution and fix their problem.

Answer (score 0):

For the `set-AzRouteConfig` operations to be performed in Azure SDK for python , It needs `az-mgmt-network` package so that it can use [NetworkManagementClient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-mgmt-network/azure.mgmt.network.v2020_06_01.networkmanagementclient?view=azure-python) Class to perform 2 operations i.e. [RouteTableOperations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-mgmt-network/azure.mgmt.network.v2020_06_01.operations.routetablesoperations?view=azure-python) and [RouteOperations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-mgmt-network/azure.mgmt.network.v2020_06_01.operations.routesoperations?view=azure-python) . For the updating the route present in a route_table you can use `begin_create_or_update`.

**Example:**

**Code:**

```
from azure.identity import AzureCliCredential
from azure.mgmt.network import NetworkManagementClient
from azure.mgmt.network.models import Route
credential = AzureCliCredential()
subscription_id = "b83c1ed3-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-2b83a074c23f"
network_client = NetworkManagementClient(credential, subscription_id)
resource_group = "ansumantest"
location = "West US 2"
route_table_name = "ansuman-routetable"
route_name = "route1"
get_table=network_client.route_tables.get(resource_group,route_table_name)
print(get_table)
route_parameters= Route(name='route1',address_prefix='10.0.0.0/32',next_hop_type='VnetLocal')
set_route_config= network_client.routes.begin_create_or_update(resource_group,route_table_name,route_name,route_parameters)
get_route_config= network_client.routes.get(resource_group,route_table_name,route_name)
print(get_route_config)
```

**Output:**

**Before Updating the route :**

[image]

**After updating the route :**

Properties changed are `address_prefix` and `next_hop_type`.

[image]